array_agg in EF Core 6
I'm working with EF Core 6 and PostgreSQL, and I need to construct a query that efficiently retrieves author names along with an array of their book titles.
My database schema:
Books

BookId (number)
AuthorId (number)
BookName (string)

Authors

AuthorId (number)
AuthorName (string)

The SQL query I'm trying to achieve is:
SELECT Authors.AuthorName, array_agg(Books.BookName)
FROM Authors
JOIN Books ON Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId
GROUP BY Authors.AuthorId

Since EF Core 6 doesn't directly support array_agg, how can I translate this into C# LINQ to SQL while prioritizing performance?
Here's what I've tried so far:
C#
from a in context.Authors
join b in context.Books
on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId
group b.BookName by a.AuthorId into g
select new 
{
    AuthorId = g.Key,
    BookNames = g.Select(name => name).ToList() 
};

Currently everything I tried when using Group By translated to join and then another leftJoin.
Is there a way for me to add a translation to array_agg?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EF is an ORM like sqlalchemy, not a query generator. Like all ORMs it's used to load graphs of related objects, not generate queries. The very fact you're using JOINs instead of relations means you're using EF wrong. You should be able to write context.Books.GroupBy(b=>b.Author.Name).Select(g=>new { Author=g.Key, Titles=g.Select(b=>b.Title).ToList()});

Ok, it could be that I am not using it right but since It is an existing system and I can't migrate everything is there something I can do??

Do you not have DbFunctions.ArrayAgg aggregate function? Maybe that was only added recently.

Use it correctly. It's a lot less code.  You don't have to migrate everything, just fix this.  Nor do you have to specify array_agg, it's up to EF to load the data and return an array. The LINQ query is wrong anyway, it's grouping the wrong things and returning a variable instead of book names. group a by a.AuthorName into g would group by author name. To get the book names, b.Select(b=>b.BookName).ToList().

Erm, GROUP BY Authors.AuthorId but SELECT Authors.AuthorName ??? If you want to use such vendor-specific syntax, why use EF at all? Use Dapper to execute the query and map the results to objecgts

DbFunctions.ArrayAgg was only added on EF core 7

@AmitHaritan, then you have no chances to do that. Use simple Eager loading query: context.Authors.Select(a => new { a.AuthorId, BookNames = a.Books.Select(b => b.BookName).ToList()})

have you tried EF function import?

It's pretty easy to just add your own custom translator for array_agg. In EF Core 7 this has now been added, but you can create a custom one yourself.
Copying bits from the official code, you first need a function you can put into the expression
public static class MyAggregateDbFunctionsExtensions
{
    public static T[] ArrayAgg<T>(this DbFunctions _, IEnumerable<T> input) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

Then a translator to create a SqlExpression from the query Expression tree.
public class MyAggregateMethodTranslator(
    NpgsqlSqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory,
    IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource,
    IModel model
) : IAggregateMethodCallTranslator
{
    private NpgsqlSqlExpressionFactory _sqlExpressionFactory = sqlExpressionFactory;
    private IRelationalTypeMappingSource _typeMappingSource = typeMappingSource;
    private IModel _model;

    public virtual SqlExpression? Translate(
        MethodInfo method,
        EnumerableExpression source,
        IReadOnlyList<SqlExpression> arguments,
        IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Query> logger)
    {
        if (source.Selector is not SqlExpression sqlExpression)
            return null;

        if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(MyAggregateDbFunctionsExtensions)
            && method.Name == nameof(MyAggregateDbFunctionsExtensions.ArrayAgg))
        {
            return _sqlExpressionFactory.AggregateFunction(
                        "array_agg",
                        [sqlExpression],
                        source,
                        nullable: true,
                        argumentsPropagateNullability: [false],
                        returnType: method.ReturnType,
                        typeMapping: sqlExpression.TypeMapping is null
                            ? null
                            : _typeMappingSource.FindMapping(method.ReturnType, _model, sqlExpression.TypeMapping));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Then a plugin to offer up that translator. You will add this to your ServicesCollection via Dependency Injection:
public class MyAggregateMethodCallTranslatorPlugin : IAggregateMethodCallTranslatorPlugin
{
    public MyAggregateMethodCallTranslatorPlugin(
        ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory,
        IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource,
        IModel model
    )
    {
        Translators = [
            new MyAggregateMethodTranslator((NpgsqlSqlExpressionFactory) sqlExpressionFactory, typeMappingSource, model),
        ];
    }

    public IEnumerable<IAggregateMethodCallTranslator> Translators { get; }
}

You add it to the ServiceCollection
services.AddScoped<IAggregateMethodCallTranslatorPlugin, MyAggregateMethodCallTranslatorPlugin>();

Then you can use it in your query like this
from a in context.Authors
join b in context.Books
on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId
group b.BookName by a.AuthorId into g
select new 
{
    AuthorId = g.Key,
    BookNames = EF.Functions.ArrayAgg(g.Select(name => name)),
}


At the end I have created a view on top of the table with a migration.
Then I used the view as a regular table in my code.
That way I didn't need to "play" with EF too much..
The only downside is that for every change I need to change the view manually in SQL in a migration.
Link for how to use views in EF core: https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/creating-views-with-entity-framework-core-9383a9a80543
